# Issue converting string to decimal with different cultures in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am developing an application where users may use files with amounts in invariant culture and at the same time other cultures (es-ES). The goal is to look for the same amount in the other grid.

I have this code where I try to convert the string with current culture and if not use the opposite culture.

(Amounts is a decimal column) 
(c01 is a nvarchar column)

```
update UserRecords set Amounts = CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(c01 AS decimal(12,2) using 'es-ES') IS NOT NULL 
THEN TRY_PARSE(c01 AS decimal(12,2) using 'es-ES') 
WHEN TRY_PARSE(c01 AS decimal(12,2) using 'en-US') IS NOT NULL 
THEN TRY_PARSE(c01 AS decimal(12,2) using 'en-US')
ELSE 0 END
```

The problem is that for example value 200.14 (using es-ES) it converts to 20014.00 and it's not the behaviour I expect.

Do I need to replace the decimal point?

Comment: That is because es-ES does not use `.` to signify the start of decimal places -- a string not formatted in that culture will not parse correctly.  I actually don't see es-ES but es is Spanish you can see below

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: There are many posts about conversion of string to decimal with commas.

Comment: if you know the culture used in the file that user uses, then use that culture. The TRY_PARSE function is to check if the string data can be parsed, not to decide what culture is used.

Comment: Btw, the en-us parse fails on the comma. So you could switch them in the case. `CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(amount AS decimal(12,2) using 'en-US') IS NOT NULL THEN PARSE(amount AS decimal(12,2) using 'en-US') ELSE ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(amount AS decimal(12,2) using 'es-ES'), 0) END`.

Comment: Note that while you *can* now solve problems like these on the SQL end courtesy of `TRY_PARSE` and friends, that definitely does not mean you *should*. Focus all effort on solving this on the client end by making sure you have determined the correct format (either from the machine's regional settings or by *asking* the user) and sending it over to SQL Server as one unambiguous, typed value. Anything else is setting yourself up for failure, as these values can be completely ambiguous -- is `1.234` one thousand two hundred thirty-four or one plus two hundred thirty-four thousandths?

Comment: @LukStorms Yes i know the culture of the pc but i dont know in wich culture are the amount columns of each file. What I expected when using TRY_PARSE function was that if I could not convert the amount with the current culture, then use the opposite culture. But the problem is that it can covert it..

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the help, yes I think i will try to solve this at the client side before sending the data to the server and forze both files to have the amounts in the same culture. 1.234 is one thousand two hundred thirty-four in spanish.